# jquery jtable - How to show newly added record in top row of table

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm using JTable latest version, JQuery 2.4.0 version. 
I create a Jtable table and it works fine
but I want when adding new record using jquery jtable . **i want to add that record to the top of the table (latest added item comes to the top most position)**
.when page reloads all records must be arrange to the given sorting order.

How can i fix it? This is my html file:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $('#GridTableContainer').jtable(
            {
                title: 'Delivery Grid Table',
                paging: true, //Enable paging
                pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
                sorting: true, //Enable sorting
                defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
                actions:
                {
                    listAction: function (postData, jtParams)
                    {
                        console.log("Loading from custom function...");
                        return $.Deferred(function ($dfd)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'ajax/grid-ajax.php?action=list&jtStartIndex=' + jtParams.jtStartIndex + '&jtPageSize=' + jtParams.jtPageSize + '&jtSorting=' + jtParams.jtSorting,
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: postData,
                                success: function (data)
                                {
                                    $dfd.resolve(data);
                                },
                                error: function ()
                                {
                                    $dfd.reject();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    createAction: 'ajax/grid-ajax.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'ajax/grid-ajax.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'ajax/grid-ajax.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    deliverygrid_id: {
                        key: true,
                        list: false,
                        title: 'id',
                    },
                    area: {
                        title: 'Express',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    price: {
                        title: 'Fee ($)',
                        width: '20%'
                    }
                }

            });






        });
        $('#GridTableContainer').jtable('load');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="GridTableContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are using default sorting for Name Column 
 `defaultSorting: 'Name ASC'` 
 change it to key column 
 `defaultSorting: 'deliverygrid_id DESC'` 
And on server side in `list` action using following code

```
if (jtSorting.Equals("deliverygrid_id DESC"))
{
    //here get data order by desc record for deliverygrid_id 
}
```

When you write `defaultSorting: 'deliverygrid_id DESC'` it means jtable sends `deliverygrid_id DESC` string value in `jtSorting` variable. 
You can find more info about sorting [Here](http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting)

Comment: then when page loads how to sort rows in ascending order...?

Comment: @Susantha7 you want default Sorting for name asc ?

Comment: yes when page loads rows are in ascending order...
when new item adds it must be come to top most position of the table...
after page loads that all rows must be sort to ascending order

Comment: @Susantha7 when we delete/add/update JTable call the 'list' function to get data. And it shows data by default sorting. I dont know how to do it but u can play with hidden fields and use 'createAction' like function as u have used for list, and check hidden field values and set 'jtParams.jtSorting'  as 'Name ASC'